# How to speed up a SQL query which is using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, distinct

From what I have read about this it seems like the best solution is to create an INDEX but I am not sure which columns I should be creating indexes for. This is my first time working with SQL indexes.

If I remove the DISTINCT call from this query I get over 1000 results in just over a second. However with the DISTINCT call it returns the results in 10 seconds (obviously without the duplicates).

If anyone has any alternative solutions I am all ears.

This is the query (the second `SELECT` is where the `DISTINCT` function is called):

```
SELECT 
    Sku,
    Name,
    ccp.Polygon,
    MarketAvailability,
    Coverage,
    Range  
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         dbo.CatalogEntry.CatalogEntryId as Id,
         dbo.CatalogEntry.Code as Sku,
         CoverageNode.Name as Coverage,
         RangeNode.Name as [Range],
         (SELECT CatalogContentProperty.LongString
          FROM CatalogContentProperty                         
          WHERE MetaFieldName = 'ItemChartName' 
            AND (CatalogContentProperty.LongString IS NOT NULL) 
            AND (CatalogContentProperty.ObjectId = dbo.CatalogEntry.CatalogEntryId)) AS [Name],
         (SELECT CatalogContentProperty.LongString
          FROM CatalogContentProperty                         
          WHERE MetaFieldName = 'MarketAvailabilityDetailsCollection' 
            AND (CatalogContentProperty.LongString IS NOT NULL) 
            AND (CatalogContentProperty.ObjectId = dbo.CatalogEntry.CatalogEntryId)) AS MarketAvailability
     FROM            
         dbo.CatalogEntry 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.NodeEntryRelation ON dbo.CatalogEntry.CatalogEntryId = dbo.NodeEntryRelation.CatalogEntryId 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.CatalogNode AS CoverageNode ON dbo.NodeEntryRelation.CatalogNodeId = CoverageNode.CatalogNodeId 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.CatalogNode AS RangeNode ON CoverageNode.ParentNodeId = RangeNode.CatalogNodeId 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.CatalogContentProperty ON dbo.CatalogEntry.CatalogEntryId = dbo.CatalogContentProperty.ObjectId 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.CatalogNode AS ModelNode ON RangeNode.ParentNodeId = ModelNode.CatalogNodeId 
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.CatalogNode AS BrandNode ON ModelNode.ParentNodeId = BrandNode.CatalogNodeId 
     WHERE        
         (dbo.CatalogEntry.ClassTypeId = N'Variation') AND
         (dbo.CatalogContentProperty.MetaFieldName = N'ItemIsChart') AND
         RangeNode.Name != 'C-MAP'  AND
         (BrandNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL) AND
         (ModelNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL) AND 
         (CoverageNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL) AND
         (RangeNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL) 
    ) AS CmapResults 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT   
         GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(CatalogContentProperty.LongString,4326) AS PolygonGeometry,
         CatalogContentProperty.LongString AS Polygon,
         CatalogContentProperty.ObjectId
     FROM       
         CatalogContentProperty                         
     WHERE   
         MetaFieldName = 'ItemChartCoordinates' AND 
         (CatalogContentProperty.LongString IS NOT NULL)) ccp ON ccp.ObjectId = CmapResults.Id 
WHERE 
    ((GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(PolygonGeometry.MakeValid().STUnion(PolygonGeometry.MakeValid().STStartPoint()).STAsText(), 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(50.9835929 -1.4205852)', 4326)) / 1609.344) <= 100 OR 'POINT(50.9835929 -1.4205852)' IS NULL)
  AND MarketAvailability IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
     GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(PolygonGeometry.MakeValid().STUnion(PolygonGeometry.MakeValid().STStartPoint()).STAsText(), 4326).STArea() DESC;
```

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012. The aim is to get the query with the DISTINCT call to return in the same amount of time as the query would without the DISTINCT call.

Comment: If you run the query with actual execution plan, do you notice if you're getting a 'Operator used tempdb to spill data' warning on the select? That warning basically means that it attempted to read all the data into memory and failing that subsequently physically wrote it to tempdb to be read later.  Not a solution but maybe a step towards one.  I have a query that takes 5m to process 480 records, I remove the distinct (which I cannot irl) and it takes 18 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `DISTINCT` on the outer `SELECT`?

Comment: This looks like a dynamic search query (based on the `AND`s and `OR`s in the `WHERE` clause), which makes indexing difficult since you are searching different columns based on the parameters. If it is a dynamic search query I would recommend that you read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). This is the canonical article on this matter (as far as I am concerned anyway), there is nothing I could possibly say that Erland hasn't already said about this.

Comment: If this runs instantly without distinct for all parameters, the it sounds like `DISTINCT` is fundamentally changing the shape of the plan. Can you post the execution plan with and without `DISTINCT`?

Comment: One thing I would try is getting rid of `DISTINCT` and using a window function with `ROW_NUMBER()`... Partition by whatever criteria you need to identify a duplicate, then filter the data in a `WHERE` clause like - `WHERE RowNum = 1`... Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Chris Should have said that I have already tried that but it didnt help.

Comment: @GarethD your right it is. But it was the DISTINCT causing the slowness rest of the query is okay

Comment: @BJones Unfortunately this didnt work

Comment: @ChristopherKlein I didnt notice any warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is my case was to remove the DISTINCT and to do the duplicate removing using LINQ! Load times went from 10-11ish seconds to 4-5ish seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks a bit complicated.  Will this one produce the same output?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ce.Code as Sku
, max(case when ccp.MetaFieldName = 'ItemChartName' then ccp.LongString end) as 'Name'
, max(case when ccp.MetaFieldName = 'MarketAvailabilityDetailsCollection' then ccp.LongString end) as 'MarketAvailability'
, max(case when ccp.MetaFieldName = 'ItemChartCoordinates' then ccp.LongString end) as 'Polygon'
, CoverageNode.Name as Coverage
, RangeNode.Name as 'Range'

FROM dbo.CatalogEntry ce
  INNER JOIN dbo.NodeEntryRelation ner ON ce.CatalogEntryId = ner.CatalogEntryId
  INNER JOIN dbo.CatalogNode CoverageNode ON dbo.NodeEntryRelation.CatalogNodeId = CoverageNode.CatalogNodeId
  INNER JOIN dbo.CatalogNode RangeNode ON CoverageNode.ParentNodeId = RangeNode.CatalogNodeId
  INNER JOIN dbo.CatalogContentProperty ccp ON ce.CatalogEntryId = ccp.ObjectId
  INNER JOIN dbo.CatalogNode ModelNode ON RangeNode.ParentNodeId = ModelNode.CatalogNodeId
  INNER JOIN dbo.CatalogNode BrandNode ON ModelNode.ParentNodeId = BrandNode.CatalogNodeId

WHERE ce.ClassTypeId = N'Variation'
  and ccp.MetaFieldName = N'ItemIsChart'
  and RangeNode.Name != 'C-MAP'
  --and (BrandNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL)      --  always true
  --and (ModelNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL)      --  always true
  --and (CoverageNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL)   --  always true
  --and (RangeNode.Name = '' OR '' = '' OR '' IS NULL)      --  always true
  and (GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(ccp.LongString,4326).MakeValid().STUnion(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(ccp.LongString,4326).MakeValid().STStartPoint()).STAsText(), 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(50.9835929 -1.4205852)', 4326)) / 1609.344) <= 100   -- OR 'POINT(50.9835929 -1.4205852)' IS NULL    --  redundant
)
and max(case when ccp.MetaFieldName = 'MarketAvailabilityDetailsCollection' then ccp.LongString end)

ORDER BY GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(ccp.LongString,4326).MakeValid().STUnion(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(ccp.LongString,4326).MakeValid().STStartPoint()).STAsText(), 4326).STArea() DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for being the only one to actually attempt to redo the query! Unfortunately it had some syntax errors I didnt know how to solve. But the collection is returned to a back end c# asp.net system so have done the duplicate removing using LINQ